# C# WebBrowser won't display embedded object

Tags: c#, html, pdf, browser, embed

This may be a dumb question, but I just can't get it to work. I'm trying to embed a pdf file into a webbrower in a c# program. Simple right? I thought so, but it proved otherwise.
Here's the html code:

```
<object classid="" type="application/pdf" width="400" height="300" id="pdf1">
<param name="src" value="Test.pdf" />
    <div style="text-align:center; color:#CCCCCC" >No Preview Available.</div>
</object>
```

And that's all thats in the html file. The funny thing is, this works perfectly in IE (which as I understand is what the WebBrowser uses). I've tried implementing the object tag the `non-IE` way, with an src attribute and whatnot, but it did the same thing. What's happening is the WebBrowser control is just displaying `No Preview Available` meaning that the pdf was not successfully embedded. Here's the c# code:

```
wbPreview.Navigate("I:/Documents/Visual Studio 2008/Projects
                      /PlanReferenceDatabase/test.html");
```

Can someone tell me why the **web browser in c# cannot display the pdf**, but the other browser can?

Answer (score 2):

Try formatting the tag like this:

```
<object type="application/pdf" data="myPdfFile.pdf" class="yourPdfClass" width="550px" height="800px"/>
```

Include the data attribute in the tag and it seems to work just fine - just tried this in my browser control on a IE8 / IE9 machine and it displays inline.

Comment: Unfortunately this still isn't working. I'm guessing it's probably a local problem with drivers or something. I'm curious though, what is the "class" element? I haven't ever seen that before.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. Just in case anyone else has the same one, here's what I did:
First I set the "target platform" property under the build tab in visual studio to x86 because as it turns out, 64bit IE can't render PDFs.
Second I used the embed tag instead of the object tag, because IE requires you to use "classid" and all sorts of Active X stuff you don't want when you use the object tag.

Comment: Any chance you could share the code for the embed that you used for your solution